# How do I use the Discoverer module with pygi GstPbutils?

Tags: python, gstreamer

I'm trying to port some pygtk music player code to pygi which uses gst's discoverer module.

```
from gi.repository import Gst, GstPbutils

def on_discovered(discoverer, ismedia):
    print("%s -- %s" %( discoverer.tags.get('title', 'Unknown'),
                        discoverer.tags.get('artist', 'Unknown')))

Gst.init(None)
location = "file:///srv/Music/molly_hatchet-the_creeper.mp3"
discoverer = GstPbutils.Discoverer()
discoverer.discover_uri(location)
discoverer.connect('discovered', on_discovered)
```

When I attempt to run this I get the following error:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/types.py:43: Warning: g_object_get_qdata: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
  return info.invoke(*args, **kwargs)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/types.py:43: Warning: g_object_ref_sink: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
  return info.invoke(*args, **kwargs)

** (python:21482): CRITICAL **: pygobject_register_wrapper: assertion `PyObject_TypeCheck(self, &PyGObject_Type)' failed
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/types.py:43: Warning: g_object_unref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
  return info.invoke(*args, **kwargs)
```

Unfortunately documentation on this pygi module seems a bit sparse.

For now I've reverted back to pygtk, but I'd love to know how to make this work with pygi since that's going to be the way forward with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

The error MSG states "python 2.7" but you are importing python3 modules. Make sure you use something like

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

At the top of your script, or invoke it with python3 explicitly.
Mind you, there seem to be [a problem with python3's GstPbutils too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38066240/how-to-import-gstpbutils) :(

Comment: The syntax of the python3 and python 2 is different in most of the segments. This might also be a problem

Comment: My point ; This is Python3 code, and should not trigger errors from a Python2.n library